# Cythonize - How to remove distribution from output so filename?

Tags: python, cythonize

I am using Ubuntu to compile cython:

```
cythonize -i  test.pyx 

Output: test.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

I need the output to be 'test.so' - Are there any options I can provide to cythonize?

Comment: I do not want to rename it after generation, I ask this because I have a use case with bazel genrule which expect the output to be exactly in the format. See: https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/89e356e37c97b62263ea3d16bdff15127501a5d5/Tools/rules.bzl#L55C11-L55C11.